# Multiple conditions in find all

Tags: cakephp, conditional-statements

i'm tring to enter some conditions in a find('all' on cake. that's my logic:

```
Traduction.traductions = my username AND Traduction.status = 1 OR 8    
OR,   Traduction.check1 = my username AND Traduction.status = 5 OR 2     
OR,   Traduction.check2 = my username AND Traduction.status = 6 OR 3    
Or,    Trauduction.editions = my username AND Traduction.status = 7 OR 3
```

If one of these condition is right, he display content

that's my code so far

```
    $conditions = array(
                'AND' => array(
                    array(
                        'OR' => array(
                            array('Traduction.traductions' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username')),
                            array('Traduction.status' => '1'),
                            array('Traduction.status' => '8')
                        )
                    ),
                'AND' => array(
                    array(
                        'OR' => array(
                            array('Traduction.check1' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username')),
                            array('Traduction.check1' => '5'),
                            array('Traduction.check1' => '2')
                        )
                    )                       
                ),
                'AND' => array(
                    array(
                        'OR' => array(
                            array('Traduction.check2' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username')),
                            array('Traduction.check2' => '6'),
                            array('Traduction.check2' => '3')
                        )
                    )                       
                ),
                'AND' => array(
                    array(
                        'OR' => array(
                            array('Traduction.edition' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username')),
                            array('Traduction.edition' => '7'),
                            array('Traduction.edition' => '4')
                        )
                    )                       
                ),

            )
    );
    $traduction = $this->Traduction->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => $conditions

    ));
```

but sadly it seems don't work. Here de sql dump

```
SELECT `Traduction`.`id`, `Traduction`.`serie`, `Traduction`.`issue`,    
`Traduction`.`page`, `Traduction`.`writer`, `Traduction`.`drawer`, 
`Traduction`.`release`, `Traduction`.`traductions`, `Traduction`.`check1`, 
`Traduction`.`check2`, `Traduction`.`edition`, `Traduction`.`user_name`, 
`Traduction`.`content`, `Traduction`.`status` FROM 
`dcomicstrad`.`traductions` AS 
`Traduction` WHERE ((((`Traduction`.`traductions` = 'DrWhat') 
OR (`Traduction`.`status` = 1) 
OR (`Traduction`.`status` = 8))) 
AND (((`Traduction`.`edition` = 'DrWhat') 
OR (`Traduction`.`edition` = '7') 
OR (`Traduction`.`edition` = '4'))))
```

Someone can please help me i'm a bit lost with all these array X_X

Comment: Simply saying *Don't work* doesn't make us understand you problem....please specify what problem you are facing, or what errors are you getting

Comment: You can make multiple condition in cakephp check this example http://goo.gl/OvDt4b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You started off quite good actually (with the OR cases), but then you trapped yourself in the same old issue: Never use an array key twice (it would just overwrite the previous one)!

```
$conditions = array(
    'AND' => array(),
    'AND' => array(),
    'AND' => array(),
```

does basically that.

Use this:

```
$conditions = array(
     array(),
     array(),
     array(),
```

You can remove the `'AND' =>` part as cake by default uses AND to connect an array of arrays.

If you want to keep the AND, you need to make it one lever deeper:

```
$conditions = array(
    'AND' => array(
         array(),
         array(),
         array(),
```

---

As a sidenote: It is still CakePHP we are talking about. Thus containing at least a little bit of magic that makes your life easier. You could simplify your query a bit here. Every OR statement could be replace by a shorter array:

```
'OR' => array(
    array('Traduction.traductions' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username')),
    array('Traduction.status' => '1'),
    array('Traduction.status' => '8')
)
```

can become

```
'OR' => array(
    array('Traduction.traductions' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username')),
    array('Traduction.status' => array('1', '8'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($this->data['Report']['ipno'])) 
        {
            $condition['DrugissueBatchIssue.patient_no like'] = "%".$this->data['Report']['ipno']."%";   
        }
        if (!empty($this->data['Report']['pname'])) 
        {
            $condition['DrugissueBatchIssue.patient_name like'] = "%".$this->data['Report']['pname']."%";   
        }             
        if (!empty($this->data['Report']['fromDate'])) 
        {
            $condition['date(DrugissueBatchIssue.created_date) >='] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->data['Report']['fromDate'])); 
        }
        if (!empty($this->data['Report']['toDate'])) 
        {
            $condition['date(DrugissueBatchIssue.created_date) <='] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->data['Report']['toDate']));             
        }
 $patient_wise_sales_report = $this->DrugissueBatchIssue->find('all', array('conditions'=>array($condition),'order'=>array('DrugissueBatchIssue.patient_no asc')));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider adding an explanation with your code. How does it answer the question exactly?